# What is the difference between `.zero_grad()` and `.zero_grad`?

Tags: python, neural-network, pytorch, gradient-descent, loss-function

I am working on neural network and I find that, with `*.grad_zero()` I get loss function values properly and also converge to zero. Where, with `*.grad_zero` (with out bracket) gives loss function values in 5 digits. (13,564.23). So, what is the difference between them? Why "()" important in FPP. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

[`optimizer.zero_grad`](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/optim.html#torch.optim.Optimizer.zero_grad) is a function, so you need to call it with parentheses. If you don't use the parentheses, you are just referencing the function object but never calling it.

Comment: and by not calling it, the gradients will be accumulating over time...